# "and" function in Pandas with positions in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, filter

I'm fairly new to python and I've been playing around trying to do things with python using pandas that would have a hard time doing in excel.

I've been trying to write code that filters data based on position number of strings and letters.

What I have so far is the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Main\Desktop\dataset.xlsx')
df.loc[df['Name'].str[1]=='a'] & df.loc[df['Name'].str[2]=='x']
```

What I am trying to do is get rows based on name.
In other words, the program filters through the "Name" column and if the second letter is an "a" and third letter an 'x' then it should print the filtered rows.

Now, I should say, this works fine when I do it with just the 'a'
So, when my code looks like the one, below, the program works.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Main\Desktop\dataset.xlsx')
df.loc[df['Name'].str[1]=='a']
```

It just when I add the '&' symbol for the additional filter is when I get the trouble.

Any advice would help. I'm fairly new to this so any advice would  be appreciated. I tried to sovle this via a for loop but I figured the approach I took above was slightly better.

Comment: Try:  `df[df['Name'].str[1]=='a' & df['Name'].str[3]=='a' ]]`

Comment: You may need to wrap the tests in parentheses to ensure they're ordered as you expect `[(test1) & (test2)]`

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt Why are you creating new accounts for asking questions? You asked a similar question in the morning a few hours back itself. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387990/python-pandas-filter-rows-based-on-position-letter-in-string/65388038#65388038). You don't award any points to the people who answer your question correctly. This is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to use parenthesis correctly when using the `&` operator:

```py
$ df = pd.DataFrame(data=['_ab', '_ax', '_xy', 'abcd'], columns=['Name'])
$ df
   Name
0   _ab
1   _ax
2   _xy
3  abcd

# Correct parenthesis are important!:
$ df.loc[(df.Name.str[1] == 'a') & (df.Name.str[2] == 'x')]
Name
1  _ax
```

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks this works. I did have a question about this though. I was wondering why it doesn't work if I replace the ".str" with ".int" or ".float". I tried this with another column that was with integters and changed the str to integter but it refused to work, I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction regarding this.

Comment: The short answer is that str is handled different from int/float. For more information about str accessor, you can go the pandas documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html.

For int/float columns, you don't need the accessor, you can just process them the columns. (`df.a > 3` for example)